# Want to display JList over the JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jtextarea

I want to disply JList over the JTextArea but its showing it behind the JTextArea. I have attached two images to describe my problem through images.At runtime how can we set JList over the JTextArea?

### JList behind JTextArea:

[image]

### JList over JTextArea:

[image]

Comment: @bsm: I think that you've got something funky going on in your code that is messing things up.  Your best bet is to create and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (please click on the link), a small compilable, runnable program that demonstrates your best attempt at solving this. Then we can inspect your code, run it, modify it and best be able to help you fix it.  Are you mixing any AWT components with your Swing components, perhaps using a Canvas or a TextArea (instead of JTextArea) object anywhere?

Comment: I want to display the list while clicking on that button and after selecting an item from the list, list will be hidden. So for that,I have used JPanel and put JList in it as I didnt found any way to set directly visibility of JList. I am using netbeans,so the code regarding my problem has been generated automatically after dragging and dropping components on the Frame.Thats the only reason,I have attached image here as there so many auto generated lines in the code.

Comment: @bsm: also, why use a JList and not the more appropriate JComboBox?  And to learn how to code Swing, you should avoid NetBeans code generation but rather use the Swing tutorials as a guide to help you learn to code it by hand.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels..Yes I totally agree..But I am a student and I have only few days to complete a big task..I really love to work hard and learn new things but only because of less days,I am using it so that can spend remaing time in learning other problems. I really appreciate everyone's comments and answers here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bsm: you should not use JLists for this situation but JComboBoxes which will have drop down lists that display correctly over the JTextArea.  For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JComboAndJTextArea extends JPanel {

   private static final String[] ITEMS1 = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
   private static final String[] ITEMS2 = {"Monday", "Tuesday", 
      "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

   public JComboAndJTextArea() {
      JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
      northPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Reminder"));
      northPanel.add(new JComboBox(ITEMS1));
      northPanel.add(new JComboBox(ITEMS2));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(8, 30)), BorderLayout.CENTER);

   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboAndJTextArea");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new JComboAndJTextArea());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

I also re-recommend that you put your NetBeans code generation to the side for the time being as I honestly believe that for many it hinders their ability to learn how to code in Swing.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that default behaviour is to show combo content over other components, thus you have it this way. The only suggestion that I would think of at the moment is to use layered pane.

You could check to which layer the part of combo box with options is added. Then add the list to one above.

Tutorial about LayeredPane http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

From this description of RootPane I think the options of combobox must be shown on popup layer http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Good luck, Boro.

Comment: rather than use a JLayeredPane as a complex kludge, wouldn't it be better to first try to help the OP find out what bug in his code is causing the abnormal behavior?

Comment: Good point my bad. I thought that he is after actually this behaviour and that the JList is at the bottom and combo at the top. Sorry, my bad.  Hovercraft Full Of Eels you are tight the code is a must to see.

Comment: Even though,I also agree with  Hovercraft Full Of Eels' point, Thanks Boro for sharing useful links.